# Augmentation layer warnings in tensorflow 2.10

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, image-augmentation

In tensorflow `2.10.0` I am trying some data augmentation layers, for example:

```
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.RandomFlip('horizontal'),
        layers.RandomRotation(0.1),#rad
        layers.RandomZoom(0.2)
    ])

#let's look at the manipulated images
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for images, _ in train_dataset.take(1):
    for i in range(9):
        augmented_images = data_augmentation(images)
        ax = plt.subplot(3,3,i+1)
        plt.imshow(augmented_images[0].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.axis("off")
```

But I get the following warnings.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting RngReadAndSkip cause there is no registered converter for this op.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting Bitcast cause there is no registered converter for this op.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting Bitcast cause there is no registered converter for this op.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting StatelessRandomUniformV2 cause there is no registered converter for this op.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using a while_loop for converting ImageProjectiveTransformV3 cause there is no registered converter for this op.
```

This is a known issue but the [only suggestion I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73304934/tensorflow-data-augmentation-gives-a-warning-using-a-while-loop-for-converting) suggest to downgrade it.

Also it's long-time known issue as shown in the [github repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/56242).

Is there any known solution or alternative to the downgrade?

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Sorry, I didn't see you were asking for the alternative to downgrade. As shown in Apple developer webpage, there is no mention of higher version than 2.9, so I don't know if they've been able to work it.

As advised in [apple developer webpage](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698217), RngReadAndSkip is registered on the GPU in tensorflow-metal==0.5.1

I upgraded from tensorflow-metal 0.5 to tensorflow-metal 0.5.1 and now it works.

Also, I followed the [instructions provided by apple](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) by aligning the versions as per table.

When following instructions provided by apple, I was getting higher tensor flow-macos and tensorflow-metal versions, and I had to downgrade to listed versions on the table.

[image: Releases versions]

I also mess around with python version, from 3.10 to 3.8, but not sure that did anything tho.

I hope it helps.